# Something is wrong with this C code to reverse string, but I dont know what ? please help

Tags: c, string, reverse

I am beginnner to programming. I wrote this little program to reverse a string. But if I try to reverse a string which is less than 5 characters long then it gives wrong output. I cant seem to find whats wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char test[50];
 char rtest[50];
 int i, j=0;
 printf("Enter string : ");
 scanf("%s", test); 
 int max = strlen(test) - 1;
 for ( i = max; i>=0; i--)
 {
  rtest[j] = test[i];
  j++;
 }
 printf("Reversal is : %s\n", rtest); 

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not terminating the reversed string with a 0. (all strings in C are 0-terminated)

In this case, the printf will (likely, depending on the unitialized contents of the rtest array) create a buffer overflow.

Add a `rtest[max+1]=0;` after the for loop and everything should be fine.
Otherwise you can declare `char rtest[50] = {0}` (this will initialize the whole array with 0s).

Comment: but why it works OK when string length is 5 or more characters ?

Comment: @Harbhag: The contents of the array `rtest` are indeterminate - and it's **undefined behavior** trying to access them (before assigning values). Sometimes it might seem to work - often it won't.

Answer (score 2):

rtest is unitialized.

You should add rtest[j] = '\0'; after the for loop to say where the string ends

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
 int len = strlen(str);
 for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; ++i) {
  char tmp = str[i];
  str[i] = str[len - 1 - i];
  str[len - 1 - i] = tmp;
 }
}
```

Comment: -1. The OP is asking about problems in his own solution. He didn't ask for a different solution that he could copy and paste. And I would give a -2 if I could for posting it without any additional comment.

Comment: another posts clearly explained the problem in his implementation. just thought he deserves to look at another solution that uses less resources.

Comment: There is no problem with this. But maybe you should say so, instead of throwing a piece of code into the room. A beginner could trip over it when it is laying around there without any context. ;)